# Bodyweight strength training

Tags: strength-training, bodyweight-exercises

Normally I'd be following a typical freeweight strength training program, like Stronglifts 5x5, but lately I have found the necessity to go to a gym is a bit of a problem. Also, I will be leaving for some delegations at work in the following months, so going to a gym will be very inconvinient or even impossible.

Im thinking of switching to a bodyweight strength training program - that way I could exercise anywhere, anytime.

**I want to replace a 5x5 program with bodyweight exercises**

I want to reach the same goals doing 5x5 helps accomplish. I want to gain strength and overall fitness. Im also in the process of getting leaner, but thats what my diet takes care of.

But I have a few doubts about all this.

- Is bodyweight training effective for strength and muscle gain?
- Are there muscle groups that such a training plan does not properly adress?
- Are bodyweight programs easy to adjust in terms of how hard they are, and is it easy to measure progress (like 2,5kg increments in 5x5)

Id be happy if you could provide me with a program that could fufill my expectations.

Ive read the [bodyweight leg exercises for strength/hypertrophy](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10155/bodyweight-leg-exercises-for-strength-hypertrophy) question, but its far from being a complete answer for my question.

Comment: Which question do you want to ask: "Is bodyweight training effective" or "Does BW training omit muscles" or "Provide me with a program"? This question needs to be one specific question, preferably with background about your goals if the question relates to programming.

Comment: @Dave Liepmann Edited my question, hope its clearer now

Comment: I'm trying to write an answer, but I keep tripping over the idea of "replacing" a 5x5 barbell program. Bodyweight strength training can be productive, but it can't replace barbells--they're fundamentally different tools.

Comment: [This answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/10021/1771) has significant overlap to your question, particularly since "replicate 5x5 with bodyweight" is in my opinion impossible.

Comment: The [Reddit Bodyweight Fitness community](http://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/faq#wiki_beginner_routine) has a fairly good explanation, there's even a simple image for quick reference: [link](http://i.imgur.com/o3bRo.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bodyweight Cannot Replicate Barbells

> Is bodyweight training effective for strength and muscle gain?

Yes. So are barbells, dumbbells, kettlebells, bands, and any other form of resistance. That does not mean they are *equally* effective.

> Are there muscle groups that such a training plan does not properly address?

Any training modality can omit muscle groups. A bodyweight training program can be designed so it does not omit any muscle groups. Right now you don't have a training program, so it can't address or omit any muscle groups.

> Are bodyweight programs easy to adjust in terms of how hard they are, and is it easy to measure progress (like 2,5kg increments in 5x5)

Sometimes. Depends what kind of bodyweight training you're doing. Most of them you can progress along some measure. Nothing will ever match barbells in precision and flexibility of measuring progress.

> I'd be happy if you could provide me with a program that could fulfill my expectations.

There is no bodyweight training program that matches your expectations. No bodyweight routine can match the results of a barbell routine, because barbell training is different than bodyweight training. 5x5 routines get the results they do, in the time they do, in the way they do, *because they use barbells*.

### 5x5 is Barbells and Bodyweight is Bodyweight

You should find a bodyweight training program and start doing it. Don't worry about getting the perfect program right now, just get started with [/r/bodyweightfitness](http://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/faq#wiki_beginner_routine) or [something from Ross Enamait](http://www.rosstraining.com/nevergymless.html) or [Building the Gymnastic Body](https://zp130.infusionsoft.com/app/storeFront/showCategoryPage?categoryId=24) or just start doing pull-ups and push-ups and sprints and squats.

But if you want to do a 5x5 routine, then go to the gym and use their barbells, or buy a barbell and squat rack.